# Regex expression for facebook profile or page

Tags: regex

This Regex expresion works like a charm:

`/^https:\/\/(?:www\.)?facebook.com\/(?:[^\s?]+)?$/ig`

For this address:
https://www.facebook.com/xxxx

But I want to raise an error if someone enters this:

- https://www.facebook.com/xxxx/
- https://www.facebook.com/xxxx/feed
- https://www.facebook.com/xxxx/comments
- https://www.facebook.com/xxxx/yyyyy
- ...

Comment: Are you trying to raise an error if there is an additional '/' character?

Comment: Yes @zrbecker, anubhava got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your regex by not allowing `/` after `facebook.com/` part.

```
/^https:\/\/(?:www\.)?facebook.com\/(?:[^\s\/?]+)?$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS3nE7/1)